# Galleria Fatal error:Theme css could not load after 20 sec

Tags: galleria

I am getting the following error in Chrome browser

> Fatal error:Theme css could not load after 20 sec

I am loading theme css in `<head>` tag using the following html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${copart.url("css/galleria/galleria.classic.css")}" name="galleria.classic">
```

and loading galleria js separately in `<body>` tag

```
<group name="galleriaJs">
        <js minimize="false">/galleria/galleria-1.3.2.min.js</js>
        <js minimize="false">/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js</js>
    </group>
```

I am opening galleria in modal window and loading all the css and js on page in parent window on page load.

As I am loading galleria.classic.min.js using script tag as per my understanding I don't need to load galleria.classic.min.js' separately in my js file using the following method:

```
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fetal errors are _not_ good, you should see a doctor.

Comment: @MikeChristensen lol, good one. John, please include the language tag that you are using, also what is the final result in the DOM for the href?

Comment: using <HTML> i have no idea how to share the dom its very long